# how to split two parameter and create label and input field based on them

Tags: jsp, jstl

I wrote a JSP with two parameters filter and filter_t. I want to split the parameter by ',' and create a label for each filter_t and input field for each filter. So I wrote code like below:

```
<c:forEach var="splt_t" items="${fn:split(param.filter_t,',')}">
    <label>${splt_t}</label>
</c:forEach>
<c:forEach var="splt" items="${fn:split(param.filter,',')}">
    <input type="text" name="${splt}" /> 
</c:forEach>
```

But in this it create two labels first and then two input fields. If I want to one label and one input field, how to modify the code? I'm sure these two parameters contain same number of ','. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code that demonstrates one solution.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "fn" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%
String f = "a,b,c,d";
String t = "1,2,3,4";
pageContext.setAttribute("f", f);
pageContext.setAttribute("t", t);
%>
<c:forEach var="splt_t" items="${fn:split(t,',')}" varStatus="tStatus">
    <label>${splt_t}</label>
    <c:forEach var="splt" items="${fn:split(f,',')}" varStatus="fStatus">
        <c:if test="${tStatus.index == fStatus.index}">
            <input type="text" name="${splt}" value="${splt}"/> 
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Another solution:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%
    String f = "a,b,c,d";
    String t = "1,2,3,4";
    pageContext.setAttribute("f", f);
    pageContext.setAttribute("t", t);
%>
<c:forTokens var="current_t" items="${t}" delims="," varStatus="tStatus">
    <label>${current_t}</label>
    <c:forTokens var="current" items="${f}" delims="," varStatus="fStatus">
        <c:if test="${tStatus.index == fStatus.index}">
            <input type="text" name="${current}" value="${current}"/> 
        </c:if>
    </c:forTokens>
</c:forTokens>
```